# How can i keep adding buttons related to what i wrote when i click the button

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Class Form3
  Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oForm As Form2 = New Form2
    Dim btn As Button = New Button With {
        .Location = New Point(300, 100),
        .Text = TextBox1.Text,
        .ForeColor = Color.Black
    }
    oForm.Controls.Add(btn)
    oForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    oForm.Show(Me)
    Me.Hide()
  End Sub
End Class
```

I want to keep adding new buttons when the button is clicked but not at the same position i want the buttons to keep adding downwards like this:

[Button1]

[Button2]

[Button3]

Comment: Are you wanting to open brand new forms each time, or just add a new button to an existing form?

Comment: Add a new button with a name depending on what someone typed, to an existing form, every time the add button is clicked

Comment: get the current position of you button1 and than create the new button on every click, changing y value of the location each time

Comment: Adding them to a FlowLayoutPanel instead of the form would be a very basic workaround.

Comment: Even with FlowLayoutPanel still does not work everytime i add a new button it overrides it again and again on the previous form.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your Button1 location and than increase the Y value every time you click on it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Button1Coordinate As Point
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim btn As Button = New Button
        Button1Coordinate.Y += 46
        With btn
            .Location = New Point(Button1Coordinate)
            .Text = TextBox1.Text
            .ForeColor = Color.Black
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(btn)
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button1Coordinate = Button1.Location
    End Sub
End Class
```

**N.B.** the default height of a button is 23 pixels

Comment: Or you could store the last Button control, then the new button's Y = LastButton.Y + LastButton.Height + 4 (if you wanted to add some space)
I'm not sure if the default height is always 23, when you have different screen DPIs etc.

Comment: I tried this it did not work every time i click the button it goes back to my Form2 but the button is placed at the same position every time

Comment: @Kadhem Really? I tried it so many times that my form was full of buttons :(